# Powerbuilder - XML - Basic Authentication

Tags: xml, jsp, authentication, powerbuilder

I am using PowerBuilder 11.5.1 and I need to send XML request to a jsp using Basic Authentication.

I cannot find how. In 11.5 you can not write .Net code.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756560/powerbuilder-call-webservice-with-basicauthentication) with [open answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53354731/3390788).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powerbuilder call WebService with BasicAuthentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756560/powerbuilder-call-webservice-with-basicauthentication)