# Powerbuilder call WebService with BasicAuthentication

Tags: xml, web-services, basic-authentication, powerbuilder

I am using PB 11.5.1 (Classic) and I want to pass an XML to a WebService that uses BasicAuth.

I cannot find how to implement the BasicAuth.

I have searched forums/blogs but I found no clear answer if it is even possible.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use an `oleobject` which uses `MSXML.ServerXMLHTTP`:

```
// args: as_username, as_password, as_basicauthstring
oleobject lole_http
string ls_response

lole_http = create oleobject

lole_http.ConnectToNewObject("msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")

lole_http.Open("POST", ls_theurl, FALSE, as_username, as_password)
lole_http.setTimeouts 5000, 5000, 10000, 10000 //ms - resolve, connect, send, receive
lole_http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + as_basicauthstring)  // set your basic auth string here

lole_http.Send(xmlToSend)

ls_response = lole_http.responseText

lole_http.DisconnectObject()
```